# Run TensorBoard Debug Plugin using Tensorflow 2.1.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorboard

I use Python 3.7 Tensorflow 2.1.0 Tensorboard 2.2.1.

I try to run the Debug Plugin of Tensorboard. When I start the plugin using following comand the page is loaded succesfully saying "Debugger is waiting for Session.run() connections..."

```
tensorboard --logdir logdir --debugger_port 7000
```

But when I execute my tf.keras model, the page will not be updated and is not jumping into the debug plugin.

Here some code snipping:

```
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(
        tf_debug.TensorBoardDebugWrapperSession(tf.compat.v1.Session(), "localhost:7000"))

log_dir = "logs\\fit\\" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

model.fit(self.df_x, self.df_y, epochs=self.epochs, verbose=2,
                                   batch_size=self.batch_size, validation_split=0.25,
                                   callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

Am I missing something? Have someone a code example to run the debug plugin on Tensorflow 2.1? I am only using tf.keras.